# React router routers not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can't seem to figure out why my router routes aren't rendering. I am in the very beginning of building my app so there isn't much code and I've tried several different methods and still nothing. I just have div's right now in the components i'm trying to route and the text inside isn't coming up - they were working when I had just the components in my App.js file before I tried routing them. Any ideas?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react- 
router-dom'
import Main from './components/Main';
import AddUser from './components/AddUser';
import EditUser from './components/EditUser';

function App() {
  return (

    <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Home</h1>  
        </header>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
            <Route path="/AddUser" component={AddUser} />
            <Route path="/edit" component={EditUser} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

// My JSON file \

```
{
  "name": "w15-crud",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `react-router-dom@6` `Route` component API changed. There is no longer a `component` prop for rendering routed components. Use the `element` prop and pass a ReactNode, a.k.a. JSX.

See [Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
    <Route path="/AddUser" element={<AddUser />} />
    <Route path="/edit" element={<EditUser />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```